# how to install "/Downloads/code_1.78.2-1683731010_amd64.deb" file getting this error

Tags: apt, package-management

Getting this error

```
birjendra@birjendra-HP-Laptop-14-bs0xx:~$ sudo apt install ./home/birjendra/Downloads/code_1.78.2-1683731010_amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
E: Unsupported file ./home/birjendra/Downloads/code_1.78.2-1683731010_amd64.deb given on commandline
```

Please help.

Comment: It should be either `sudo apt install /home/birjendra/Downloads/code_1.78.2-1683731010_amd64.deb` without the `.`, or `sudo apt install ./Downloads/code_1.78.2-1683731010_amd64.deb` without `/home/birjendra` if you're already in `/home/birjendra`, or `sudo apt install ~/Downloads/code_1.78.2-1683731010_amd64.deb`

Answer (score 1):

The command that you ran has wrong syntax. You are already in the home directory so You can directly access Downloads from there;

So its not

```
sudo apt install ./home/birjendra/Downloads/code_1.78.2-1683731010_amd64.deb
```

Take a fresh terminal and follow;

```
cd Downloads
```

or

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

Once you are in the Downloads directory(type `pwd` in the Terminal to verify you're in Downloads),

```
sudo dpkg -i code_1.78.2-1683731010_amd64.deb
```

That should install the package to `/home/birjendra`

Hope it helps!!